# ruby rest-client: make it never timeout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

I am trying to use ruby [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client/) to upload a large number of images to a site that I'm writing. My code looks like:

```
RestClient.post url, :timeout => 90000000, :open_timeout => 90000000, :file_param => file_obj
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
RestClient::RequestTimeout: Request Timeout
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:174:in `transmit'
    from /Library/Ruby/
```

But when I look at the server log

```
Completed in 61493ms (View: 2, DB: 1) | 201 Created
```

So there doesn't appear to be any reason why this is timing out. Anyone have any idea if there is a timeout param I am not correctly setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

This syntax sets the timeout as request header (see RestClient.post signature), if you want to use the timeout parameter you must use:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :post, :url => @url, :timeout => 90000000)
```

see: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/request.rb#L12

Comment: RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :post, :url => @url, :timeout => 90000000)

Comment: And put any parameters to be sent in the POST body (I think `:file_param` in the OP) into `:payload`  : `Request.execute(:method => :post, :url => @url, :timeout => 90000000, :payload => { :file_param => file_obj })`

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the docs, you can pass -1 through RestClient.execute timeout param:

```
# * :timeout and :open_timeout passing in -1 will disable the timeout by setting the corresponding net timeout values to nil
```

It can be used as follows:

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new(
  "url",
  :timeout => -1,
  :open_timeout => -1
response = resource.get :params => {<params>}
```

Comment: This appears to have been updated to `nil` rather than -1. Using -1 logs a warning (but appears to work).

Answer (score 4):

I have used following code and works like a charm as pointed out by Richard

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new "url", 
                                    :timeout => $TIMEOUT, 
                                    :open_timeout => $OPEN_TIMEOUT

response = resource.get  :params => { ..... }
```

Answer (score 4):

I already use RestClient.get and RestClient.post extensively, so for me, it was easier to 'Monkey Patch' RestClient. I would recommend using `RestClient::Resource.new` or `RestClient::Request.Execute` if possible.

However, since I'm lazy, and don't want to go swap out every occurrence of `RestClient.get` / `RestClient.post` in my code, I've decided to take a shortcut.

```
$timeout = 30
$open_timeout = 30

module RestClient2
  include RestClient

  def self.get(url, headers={}, &block)
    Request.execute(:method => :get, :url => url, :headers => headers, 
     :timeout => $timeout, :open_timeout => $open_timeout, &block)
  end

  def self.post(url, payload, headers={}, &block)
    Request.execute(:method => :post, :url => url, :payload => payload, :headers => headers,
     :timeout => $timeout, :open_timeout => $open_timeout, &block)
  end
end
```

And than I just just quick replaced RestClient.get/post with `RestClient2.get`/post.

It would be nice, if `RestClient::Request` had a default timeout specified, like:

```
  @timeout = args[:timeout] || 30
  @open_timeout = args[:open_timeout] || 30
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm having similar issues. A quick dive into the source reveals this bit of unfriendliness:

```
def self.post(url, payload, headers={}, &block)
  Request.execute(:method => :post, :url => url, :payload => payload, :headers => headers, &block)
end
```

Unless I'm missing something, the timeout options aren't passed on to the underlying request. Time for a patch ...

Comment: A slightly deeper dive shows that while the `get`, `post` and related convenience methods indeed do not allow you to pass the `:timeout` and `:open_timout` options, they are just thin wrappers for `Request.execute`, which will accept them.  Better to replace calls to the wrappers with calls to `execute` than to monkey patch, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

The RestClient::Resource.new() allows you to set :timeout and :open_timeout values that will get passed to the Request.execute method, when you use the resource's get, post, put, etc methods