# How to set timeout in RestClient gem in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, timeout, rest-client

I am using RestClient gem by making get call to the server through it. The question is how do I set the timeout from client side.

```
RestClient.get "http://127.0.0.1:7819/tokenize/word/stackoverflow"
```

I want to set it to 10 seconds.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You don't need to monkey patch anything. You can use `RestClient::Request` directly, like:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :get, :url => url, :timeout => 10, :open_timeout => 10)
```

But remember the worst case scenario is 20 seconds.

Check the other post answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445421/565999

Comment: This should be the answer - I'm afraid that I must assert that monkey patches are evil due to the unintended side effects they have.

Comment: nit: you don't have to specify both timeout and open_timeout if those two are same value. timeout value will be used for both read_timeout and open_timeout.
https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/10d3599745a134fa69eccc2f16f6e70133a3bb6c/lib/restclient/request.rb#L130

Comment: When using **RestClient::Resource**, could try `RestClient::Resource.new('http://slow', :timeout => 10)`